# Ivy: bad module name

Tags: xml, maven, ant, ivy

I'm using Ant with Ivy to build a multi module project.

I'm having problems with my ivy.xml file. I have no idea what I have done wrong.

**Error message:**

> my-repository: bad organisation found in /path_to_my_application/ivy.xml:
>
> expected='junit' found='my-org'
>
> my-repository: bad module name found in /path_to_my_application/ivy.xml:
>
> expected='junit found='my-module'

**Ivy.xml file:**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="my-org" module="my-module" /> 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I've trawled the internet with no luck.

Posting under `maven` too as I've seen this floating around on a few maven forums, but without any success.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your problem. The following project resolves dependencies without error

```
├── build.xml
└── ivy.xml
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="my-org" module="my-module" /> 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: +1 thanks for this. I'm starting to suspect it must be a local config error, as syntax matches documentation. Will test on another box. Leaving question open in case someone has an answer as to **why** this problem is happening.

Comment: @alex you mentioned it was a multi-module build. Perhaps that may be a consideration? My simple use case just proves that the ivy file is ok on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error today. I have ivy.xml at repository location of dependencies and also referring ivy.xml when calling ivy resolve. For ex:

```
 <ivy:resolve file="ivy-3rdpartypkgs.xml"/>
```

After I removed ivy.xml at repo location, it successfully downloaded dependencies.